Use ROS to connect raspberry pi 5 with ubuntu24 and laptop with ubuntu20
I would appreciate for the advice about real right platform to ask!
So the scenario is like this:
I have installed Ubuntu24 on a Raspberry Pi 5, in order to run ROS2 (not yet ready). And my laptop has Ubuntu20 installed as well as ROS Noetic. I would like to know whether and how I can connect these 2 devices through ROS, although both the OS and ROS versions are different.
Let's say,for example, just simple communication, e.g. RPi with ROS2 publishes a message, and laptop with ROS Noetic subscribes it.
I haven't found any helpful posts or instructions about how to do this, so I would be grateful for any advice to have a try.

The only (standard) supported way to do communication between ROS1 and ROS2 is to use the ROS2 bridge. You will need to follow the build and deploy instructions in the README.
Generally speaking this is more of a stopgap solution. It works for small projects, but in my experience can introduce a lot of overhead, especially when using the dynamic bridge for a large number of topics. Trying to be consistent on ros version and distros will always give you the best performance.
